# iOS App in "Waiting for review" stage, if I release a new build do I have to repeat the process?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My first iOS app is currently at the "Waiting for Review" stage on iTunes Connect.

Now, we are working on some bug fixes and I need to upload a new build, however, I would like to release the app as soon as possible.

My question is after an app is accepted, how long approximately does it take for Apple to review a new build / version for an app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as always, 7 to 10 days. Except when you ask for an expedited review, but then you should have a really good reason (and a really popular app ;-).

Answer (score 3):

Also see http://appreviewtimes.com to get an idea of current waiting times, based on developers self-reporting on Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you change your binary you go back to the end of the review line. The time varies depending on how busy the review team is.

The bulk of the time seems to be in "waiting for review." The actual review process seems to be pretty quick, assuming they don't need more info from you to make their decision.

The process of getting fixes to a rejected build seems to be faster than the original review process.

I would suggest planning on an app review taking 10 days. It might take less time, but that seems to be fairly typical.

Answer (score 1):

94% of all iOS app updates are reviewed within 5 business days at the moment.

You can always check https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store to get the latest info on that.